# Random boolean 70/30 inside function?

Tags: javascript, random, boolean

I am running a script in my console for swiping on the Tinder's webpage with the following script:

https://github.com/dhrubesh/Tinder/blob/master/tinder.js

But now it can be seen as a bot as it keeps constantly swiping to right and therefor I want to have 70/30 rule for swiping and modified the following:

```
var random_boolean = Math.random() < 0.7; //Random boolean added
let run = true, time_step = 1000;
const wait = (n = 1) => new Promise((rs, rj) => run ? setTimeout(rs, n) : rj()),
  click = async (cn, i = 0) => {
    document.getElementsByClassName(cn)[i].click();
    return wait(time_step)
  };
document.onkeydown = (e = window.event) => {
  if (e.key === "a") run = run ? true : explore() || true;
  else if (e.key === "z") console.log(time_step *= 0.9);
  else if (e.key === "x") console.log(time_step *= 1.1);
  else run = false;
};
const explore = async () =>
  click("recCard__info").then(() =>
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("bullet")).reduce((p, e) =>
      p.then(() => {
        e.click();
        return wait(time_step)
      }), Promise.resolve())
  ).then(() => {
    // This if statement below doesn't work
    if(random_boolean){
      click("recsGamepad__button--like")
    }else{
      click("recsGamepad__button--dislike")
    }
    //click("recsGamepad__button--like")  <-- this works if there is no if statement
  }

  ).then(() => explore());
explore();
```

Comment: Your `random_boolean` looks like it's only computed once.

Comment: How can I make it act like an infinite loop?

Comment: `var random_boolean = Math.random() < 0.7; ` doesn't magically recalculate the value. Use `function random_boolean() {return Math.random() < 0.7}` and `if (random_boolean())` or simply `if (Math.random() < 0.7)`

Comment: That still doesn't work using it like:
`function random_boolean() {
    return Math.random() < 0.7
}`
`if (random_boolean()){
      click("recsGamepad__button--like")
    }else{
      click("recsGamepad__button--dislike")
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the assignment inside the function, so the variable is recalculated every time.

```
).then(() => {
    var random_boolean = Math.random() < 0.7;
    if(random_boolean){
      click("recsGamepad__button--like")
    }else{
      click("recsGamepad__button--dislike")
    }
```